# Kali Linux Update

Tags: linux

не могу сделать апдейт, прописываю **# apt-get update** и вот что выдаёт:

```
Игн http://security.kali.org sana/updates InRelease
Игн http://http.kali.org sana InRelease    
Игн http://http.kali.org sana Release.gpg  
Игн http://security.kali.org sana/updates Release.gpg
Игн http://http.kali.org sana Release      
Игн http://security.kali.org sana/updates Release
Ош  http://security.kali.org sana/updates/main Sources                         
  404  Not Found
Ош  http://http.kali.org sana/main Sources                                     
  404  Not Found
Ош  http://security.kali.org sana/updates/contrib Sources                      
  404  Not Found
Ош  http://http.kali.org sana/non-free Sources                                 
  404  Not Found
Ош  http://http.kali.org sana/contrib Sources
  404  Not Found
Ош  http://security.kali.org sana/updates/non-free Sources
  404  Not Found
Ош  http://http.kali.org sana/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ош  http://security.kali.org sana/updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ош  http://http.kali.org sana/non-free i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ош  http://security.kali.org sana/updates/contrib i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ош  http://http.kali.org sana/contrib i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ош  http://security.kali.org sana/updates/non-free i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Игн http://http.kali.org sana/contrib Translation-ru_RU
Игн http://security.kali.org sana/updates/contrib Translation-ru_RU
Игн http://http.kali.org sana/contrib Translation-ru                           
Игн http://security.kali.org sana/updates/contrib Translation-ru               
Игн http://http.kali.org sana/contrib Translation-en                           
Игн http://security.kali.org sana/updates/contrib Translation-en
Игн http://http.kali.org sana/main Translation-ru_RU
Игн http://security.kali.org sana/updates/main Translation-ru_RU
Игн http://security.kali.org sana/updates/main Translation-ru
Игн http://http.kali.org sana/main Translation-ru                              
Игн http://security.kali.org sana/updates/main Translation-en                  
Игн http://http.kali.org sana/main Translation-en                              
Игн http://security.kali.org sana/updates/non-free Translation-ru_RU
Игн http://security.kali.org sana/updates/non-free Translation-ru              
Игн http://http.kali.org sana/non-free Translation-ru_RU                       
Игн http://security.kali.org sana/updates/non-free Translation-en
Игн http://http.kali.org sana/non-free Translation-ru
Игн http://http.kali.org sana/non-free Translation-en
W: Не удалось получить http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/non-free/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/contrib/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/contrib/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/non-free/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Не удалось получить http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Некоторые индексные файлы не скачались. Они были проигнорированы или вместо них были использованы старые версии.
```

Comment: ну так [актуализируйте](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) содержимое `/etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отредактируйте свой sources.list

```
# vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Retired Kali sana (2.0) Repositories
For access to the retired sana repositories, have the following entries in your sources.list:

```
deb http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
```

[оф документация](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)

Comment: пожалуйста переведите ваш ответ т.к. на данном сайте принято отписываться на русском языке